# Using the .loc function of the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a pandas dataframe whose one of the column is :

```
 a = [1,0,1,0,1,3,4,6,4,6]
```

now i want to create another column such that any value greater than 0 and less than 5 is assigned 1 and rest is assigned 0 ie:

```
a = [1,0,1,0,1,3,4,6,4,6]
b = [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0]
```

now i have done this

```
dtaframe['b'] = dtaframe['a'].loc[0 < dtaframe['a'] < 5] = 1
dtaframe['b'] = dtaframe['a'].loc[dtaframe['a'] >4 or dtaframe['a']==0] = 0
```

but the code throws and error . what to do ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) to get Boolean values, then `astype` to convert from Boolean values to 0/1:

```
dtaframe['b'] = dtaframe['a'].between(0, 5, inclusive=False).astype(int)
```

The resulting output:

```
   a  b
0  1  1
1  0  0
2  1  1
3  0  0
4  1  1
5  3  1
6  4  1
7  6  0
8  4  1
9  6  0
```

**Edit**

For multiple ranges, you could use [`pandas.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
dtaframe['b'] = pd.cut(dtaframe['a'], bins=[0,1,6,9], labels=False, include_lowest=True)
```

You'll need to be careful about how you define `bins`.  Using `labels=False` will return integer indicators for each bin, which happens to correspond with the labels you provided.  You could also manually specify the labels for each bin, e.g. `labels=[0,1,2]`, `labels=[0,17,19]`, `labels=['a','b','c']`, etc.  You may need to use `astype` if you manually specify the labels, as they'll be returned as categories.

Alternatively, you could combine `loc` and `between` to manually specify each range:

```
dtaframe.loc[dtaframe['a'].between(0,1), 'b'] = 0
dtaframe.loc[dtaframe['a'].between(2,6), 'b'] = 1
dtaframe.loc[dtaframe['a'].between(7,9), 'b'] = 2
```

Comment: @root brilliant answer :) what if i have to make 3 class . like from 0-1 assigned 0 , 2-6 assign 1 and finally from 7-9 assign 3 . thanks for answering

Comment: @AnuragPandey: I've made an edit to address multiple ranges.  You may want to make it a separate question though, in order to get more input.  My method may not be optimal.

Answer (score 2):

When using comparison operators and boolean logic to filter dataframes you can't use the pythonic idiom of `a < myseries < b`.  Instead you need to `(a < myseries) & (myseries < b)`

```
cond1 = (0 < dtaframe['a'])
cond2 = (dtaframe['a'] <= 5)
dtaframe['b'] = (cond1 & cond2) * 1
```

Comment: I learned about it yesterday, there is also `myseries.between(a, b)` ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html))

Comment: @ayhan I was just about to include that too :-)

Comment: @piRSquared it seemed to be throwing some error :( 'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()'.

Comment: My apologies. I wasn't paying attention.

Comment: i guess the problem is in using **dtaframe['a'].loc**.......... what do you say ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this with [np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
dtaframe['b'] = np.where(([dtaframe['a'] > 4) | (dtaframe['a']==0),0, dtaframe['a'])
```